# Replace props with useContext in React Application

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-props, react-state-management

Is there any downside to creating a state object in a parent React component and passing data up and down between nested components using useContext?   Would that eliminated the need for props all together?  Seems like a much easier and logical way to organize the data.   Is there any performance or other concerns to this method?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a few notes that should be considered beforehand:

0. You can't pass data up as [Data Flows Down](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#the-data-flows-down).
1. Passing props between nested components will lead to an anti-pattern - ["props drilling"](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/prop-drilling/)
2. The solution to "props drilling" is `Context` API

But, in use of "Context Only" (as you suggest) may lead to an anti-pattern as well ("Context Hell"?),
as for **every** data pass, you will create a `Context` and render a `Provider`.

Also, the main problem I see with this approach is that **every component that using context will render on change of the provider value**, although they might not use the context's value.

Note the render of components `3,4`:

```
const Context = React.createContext();

const Child = ({ id }) => {
  console.log(`rendered`, id);
  return <div>Child with id = {id}</div>;
};

const UsingContext = ({ id }) => {
  useContext(Context);
  console.log(`rendered using Context`, id);
  return <div>Using Context id = {id}</div>;
};

const MemoizedUsingContext = React.memo(UsingContext);
const Memoized = React.memo(Child);

const App = () => {
  const [value, render] = useReducer(p => p + 1, 0);

  return (
    <Context.Provider value={value}>
      <Child id={1} />
      <Memoized id={2} />
      <UsingContext id={3} />
      <MemoizedUsingContext id={4} />
      <button onClick={render}>Render</button>
    </Context.Provider>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit blue-meadow-0pxzr]

Comment: Thank you for the example.  Played around with it and cleared things up for me.

Comment: The example fails with "Uncaught TypeError: dispatch is not a function" when I click the render button.

Comment: @TomasPrado fixed, the updated API should be reversed